# Selenium Accessor not storing variable

Tags: selenium, accessor

I would like to store a value that's inside the inner HTML of a span tag of id="ctl00_body_BatchEditor_LblBatchIdentifyingNumber" with the Selenium IDE.  And then I want to take that variable and use the "type" command to place that value inside of an input field.

**(1)** I'm having trouble with the commands for this Test Case.

**(2)** I'd want to take this variable and use it in the same Test Case, and would also like to use it in a different Test Case.   Is this possible?

**Command to store variable:**

Command: storeValue
Target: xpath=//span[@id='ctl00_body_BatchEditor_LblBatchIdentifyingNumber']
Value: batchId

**Command to use the variable:**

Command: type
Target: ctl00_body_QuickDataEntryEditor_TxtBatchId
Value: ${batchId}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out.  When I used the "storeText" Accessor command rather than the "storeValue" Accessor command, the variable got stored and it worked.